# Does DDL Statement like ALTER which adds a new column on an existing table leads to LOSS OF clustering key definition

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

- To start with, I had a SF table with Clustering keys defined
- I took a clone of the table using CLONE statement
- I checked that the clone retained the Clustering keys and metrics

  **Question**: Do you think a column addition via ALTER statement will lead to 
  loss of  clustering keys and metric

Comment: Question for what cause of that question

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see adding a column won't impact on/disrupt the clustering keys/metrics. In some cases dropping a column might, but not adding them.

Perhaps have a go testing this - maybe make a clone of your cloned table and try adding columns to that to assess the impact.